# Avoiding Page Refresh Event while Clicking Button Multiple times in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page where I have a button "Add More". Whenever I click on this button my "rowNum" incremented by 1 and does the job. Now, it is working perfectly without clicking page refresh button.But, whenever I click page refresh the previous action which was done by "Add More" executed once again. I have seen every possible solution to avoid page refresh in oline platforms but there the solution is something like when they detect it's a page refresh they avoid it in the case of submitting a form but here in my case I can't do that as I have to click the "Add More" button again and again even while a user click the refresh button in the middle. I have been trying for a workable solution for days,please help me out. I am attching my code below:

```
    static int rowNum;
        string applicantUserid = "";
        EmployeeHistDS employeeHistDS = new EmployeeHistDS();
        EmployeeHistDS universityDS = new EmployeeHistDS();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                loadCompanyInfo();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    rowNum = 1;
                    if (this.Context.User.Identity.Name != "")
                    {
                        hdnApplicantUserID.Value = this.Context.User.Identity.Name;
                        loadCombo();
                        divMessageFailed.Visible = false;
                        divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
                        RecruitmentDS eduDS = UtilUI.GetApplicantEducationList(Convert.ToInt32(hdnApplicantUserID.Value));
                        if (eduDS != null && eduDS.Job_Applicant_EduInfo.Rows.Count > 0) loadUserCombo(eduDS);

                        JobDetailsDS jobsDS = new JobDetailsDS();
                        if (this.Context.User.Identity.Name != "") jobsDS = UtilUI.GetApplicantBasicInformation(this.Context.User.Identity.Name);
                        if (jobsDS != null && jobsDS.Job_Application.Rows.Count > 0 && !jobsDS.Job_Application[0].IsAPPLICANTNAMENull()) loginUserName.Text = "Welcome, <span class='bold' style='color:orange'>" + jobsDS.Job_Application[0].APPLICANTNAME + "</span>";
                        loginUserName.Visible = true;
                        login.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null && UtilUI.Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString()) != "")
                    {
                        hdnApplicantUserID.Value = UtilUI.Decrypt(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
                        loadCombo();
                        divMessageFailed.Visible = false;
                        divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
                        logout.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        loadCombo();
                        divMessageFailed.Visible = true;
                        lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblError.Text = "Please Fill Up Personal Information First to Add Education.";
                        divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
                        logout.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    employeeHistDS = UtilUI.getDegreeList();
                    universityDS = UtilUI.getUniversityList();
                    _clearValidationMsg();
                    if (hdnApplicantUserID.Value == "")
                    {
                        divMessageFailed.Visible = true;
                        lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                        lblError.Text = "Please Fill Up Personal Information First to Add Education.";
                        divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        divMessageFailed.Visible = false;
                        divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
                    }
                }
                MenuItemUrl();
            }
            catch { }

        }
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rowNum != 8)
            {
                rowNum++;
                if (rowNum == 2) addNewRow2();
                else if (rowNum == 3) addNewRow3();
                else if (rowNum == 4) addNewRow4();
                else if (rowNum == 5) addNewRow5();
                else if (rowNum == 6) addNewRow6();
                else if (rowNum == 7) addNewRow7();
                else if (rowNum == 8) addNewRow8();
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = "You Can Add Max 5 Post Graduation Information.";
                lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                divMessageFailed.Visible = true;
                divMessageSuccess.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

I have attached an image for your better understanding:
  [this is the case scenerio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WEfh.jpg)
Thank you.

Comment: Here is your trick http://geekswithblogs.net/Vipin/archive/2011/06/08/detecting-browser-refresh-from-code-behind-in-.net.aspx  .. if refresh dont execute your code

Comment: @HanyHabib I know that solution already but that is not the case here. I can't avoid page refresh as I have to click "Add More" button again and again even after page refresh button is clicked and that is why that solution will not work for me.

Comment: Have you considered disabling the button using JS when it is clicked?

Comment: yes I have,but I am little bit confused here.If I disable my button using JavaScript then how will I re-enable it as I need to click it after a user click on page refresh?